# Using relative paths in Qt stylesheet urls

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, relative-path, qtstylesheets

I have trouble reading the images in a `.qss` file. The organizations is as following:

- How can I fix this bug ?
- Is there a proper way to append all folders/subfolder to the path of the main application `main.py`. I have tried `sys.path.append('./images')`, but it always requires the absolute path to any image or icon ?

Example Code (Note that No icons are appearing (no down_arrow for QCombobox, and no question icon for messagebox)):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):       
        self.hbox  = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItem('item_1')
        self.combo.addItem('item_2')
        self.combo.setCurrentText('item_1')
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.combo)
        
        self.bt = QPushButton('Question')
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.bt)
        self.bt.clicked.connect(self.openMess)

        # style
        file       = QFile(r'./themes/DarkBlue.qss')
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
        stylesheet = file.readAll()
        app.setStyleSheet(str(stylesheet, encoding='utf-8'))

    def openMess(self):
        buttonReply    = QMessageBox.question(self, 'No Image', "Check icons", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print('Yup')
        else:
            print('Nup')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is a sample of the `.qss` file i use. The `images` folder is a subfolder at same location as the `.qss` file:

```
QMenuBar
{
    background-color: #302F2F;
    color: silver;
}

QMenuBar::item
{
    background: transparent;
}

QMenuBar::item:selected
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed
{
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    background-color: #3d8ec9;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}

QMenu
{
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    color: silver;
    margin: 1px;
}

QMenu::icon
{
    margin: 1px;
}

QMenu::item
{
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* reserve space for selection border */
}

QMenu::item:selected
{
    color: black;
}

QMenu::separator {
    height: 2px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

QMenu::indicator {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

/* non-exclusive indicator = check box style indicator
   (see QActionGroup::setExclusive) */
QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked {
    image: url(images/checkbox_unchecked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked:selected {
    image: url(images/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked {
    image: url(images/checkbox_checked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked:selected {
    image: url(images/checkbox_checked_disabled.png);
}

/* exclusive indicator = radio button style indicator (see QActionGroup::setExclusive) */
QMenu::indicator:exclusive:unchecked {
    image: url(images/radio_unchecked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:unchecked:selected {
    image: url(images/radio_unchecked_disabled.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked {
    image: url(images/radio_checked.png);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked:selected {
    image: url(images/radio_checked_disabled.png);
}

QMenu::right-arrow {
    margin: 5px;
    image: url(images/right_arrow.png)
}


QWidget:disabled
{
    color: #808080;
    background-color: #302F2F;
}

QAbstractItemView
{
    alternate-background-color: #3A3939;
    color: silver;
    border: 1px solid 3A3939;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
}

QWidget:focus, QMenuBar:focus
{
    border: 1px solid #78879b;
}

QTabWidget:focus, QCheckBox:focus, QRadioButton:focus, QSlider:focus
{
    border: none;
}

QLineEdit
{
    background-color: #201F1F;
    padding: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: silver;
}

QGroupBox {
    border:1px solid #3A3939;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    color: silver;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: top center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

QAbstractScrollArea
{
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    background-color: transparent;
}

QScrollBar:horizontal
{
    height: 15px;
    margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #2A2929;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal
{
    background-color: #605F5F;
    min-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal
{
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-image: url(images/right_arrow_disabled.png);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal
{
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-image: url(images/left_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on
{
    border-image: url(images/right_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}


QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on
{
    border-image: url(images/left_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
{
    background: none;
}


QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
{
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar:vertical
{
    background-color: #2A2929;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical
{
    background-color: #605F5F;
    min-height: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
{
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(images/up_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
{
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(images/down_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on
{

    border-image: url(images/up_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}


QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on
{
    border-image: url(images/down_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
{
    background: none;
}


QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
{
    background: none;
}

QTextEdit
{
    background-color: #201F1F;
    color: silver;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
}

QPlainTextEdit
{
    background-color: #201F1F;;
    color: silver;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
}

QHeaderView::section
{
    background-color: #3A3939;
    color: silver;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}

QSizeGrip {
    image: url(images/sizegrip.png);
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}

QMainWindow
{
    background-color: #302F2F;

}

QMainWindow::separator
{
    background-color: #302F2F;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    spacing: 2px;
    border: 1px dashed #3A3939;
}

QMainWindow::separator:hover
{

    background-color: #787876;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    spacing: 2px;
}


QMenu::separator
{
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #3A3939;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


QFrame
{
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
}

QFrame[frameShape="0"]
{
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px transparent #444;
}

QStackedWidget
{
    background-color: #302F2F;
    border: 1px transparent black;
}

QToolBar {
    border: 1px transparent #393838;
    background: 1px solid #302F2F;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QToolBar::handle:horizontal {
    image: url(images/Hmovetoolbar.png);
}
QToolBar::handle:vertical {
    image: url(images/Vmovetoolbar.png);
}
QToolBar::separator:horizontal {
    image: url(images/Hsepartoolbar.png);
}
QToolBar::separator:vertical {
    image: url(images/Vsepartoolbars.png);
}

QPushButton
{
    color: silver;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #4A4949;
    border-style: solid;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* outline: none; */
    /* min-width: 40px; */
}

QPushButton:disabled
{
    background-color: #302F2F;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #3A3939;
    border-style: solid;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    /*border-radius: 2px;*/
    color: #808080;
}

QPushButton:focus {
    background-color: #3d8ec9;
    color: white;
}

QComboBox
{
    selection-background-color: #3d8ec9;
    background-color: #201F1F;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    min-width: 75px;
}

QPushButton:checked{
    background-color: #4A4949;
    border-color: #6A6969;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border: 2px solid #78879b;
    color: silver;
}

QComboBox:hover, QAbstractSpinBox:hover,QLineEdit:hover,QTextEdit:hover,QPlainTextEdit:hover,QAbstractView:hover,QTreeView:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #78879b;
    color: silver;
}

QComboBox:on
{
    background-color: #626873;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    selection-background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
    background-color: #201F1F;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    selection-background-color: #3d8ec9;
    color: silver;
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 15px;

    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(images/down_arrow_disabled.png);
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on, QComboBox::down-arrow:hover,
QComboBox::down-arrow:focus
{
    image: url(images/down_arrow.png);
}

QPushButton:pressed
{
    background-color: #484846;
}

QAbstractSpinBox {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    background-color: #201F1F;
    color: silver;
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-width: 75px;
}

QAbstractSpinBox:up-button
{
    background-color: transparent;
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
}

QAbstractSpinBox:down-button
{
    background-color: transparent;
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: bottom right;
}

QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow,QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:disabled,QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:off {
    image: url(images/up_arrow_disabled.png);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:hover
{
    image: url(images/up_arrow.png);
}


QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow,QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:disabled,QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:off
{
    image: url(images/down_arrow_disabled.png);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:hover
{
    image: url(images/down_arrow.png);
}


QLabel
{
    border: 0px solid black;
}

QTabWidget{
    border: 1px transparent black;
}

QTabWidget::pane {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}

QTabBar
{
    qproperty-drawBase: 0;
    left: 5px; /* move to the right by 5px */
}

QTabBar:focus
{
    border: 0px transparent black;
}

QTabBar::close-button  {
    image: url(images/close.png);
    background: transparent;
}

QTabBar::close-button:hover
{
    image: url(images/close-hover.png);
    background: transparent;
}

QTabBar::close-button:pressed {
    image: url(images/close-pressed.png);
    background: transparent;
}

/* TOP TABS */
QTabBar::tab:top {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    border: 1px solid #4A4949;
    border-bottom: 1px transparent black;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}

QTabBar::tab:top:!selected
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #201F1F;
    border: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-bottom: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

QTabBar::tab:top:!selected:hover {
    background-color: #48576b;
}

/* BOTTOM TABS */
QTabBar::tab:bottom {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    border: 1px solid #4A4949;
    border-top: 1px transparent black;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:!selected
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #201F1F;
    border: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-top: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:!selected:hover {
    background-color: #78879b;
}

/* LEFT TABS */
QTabBar::tab:left {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    border: 1px solid #4A4949;
    border-left: 1px transparent black;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:!selected
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #201F1F;
    border: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-right: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:!selected:hover {
    background-color: #48576b;
}


/* RIGHT TABS */
QTabBar::tab:right {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    border: 1px solid #4A4949;
    border-right: 1px transparent black;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:!selected
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #201F1F;
    border: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-right: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:!selected:hover {
    background-color: #48576b;
}

QTabBar QToolButton::right-arrow:enabled {
     image: url(images/right_arrow.png);
 }

 QTabBar QToolButton::left-arrow:enabled {
     image: url(images/left_arrow.png);
 }

QTabBar QToolButton::right-arrow:disabled {
     image: url(images/right_arrow_disabled.png);
 }

 QTabBar QToolButton::left-arrow:disabled {
     image: url(images/left_arrow_disabled.png);
 }


QDockWidget {
    border: 1px solid #403F3F;
    titlebar-close-icon: url(images/close.png);
    titlebar-normal-icon: url(images/undock.png);
}

QDockWidget::close-button, QDockWidget::float-button {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: transparent;
}

QDockWidget::close-button:hover, QDockWidget::float-button:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);
}

QDockWidget::close-button:pressed, QDockWidget::float-button:pressed {
    padding: 1px -1px -1px 1px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);
}

QTreeView, QListView, QTextBrowser, AtLineEdit, AtLineEdit::hover {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    color: black;
}

QTreeView:branch:selected, QTreeView:branch:hover {
    background: url(images/transparent.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(images/transparent.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(images/transparent.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(images/transparent.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
    image: url(images/branch_closed.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
    image: url(images/branch_open.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed:hover,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings:hover {
    image: url(images/branch_closed-on.png);
    }

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings:hover,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings:hover  {
    image: url(images/branch_open-on.png);
    }

QListView::item:!selected:hover, QListView::item:!selected:hover, QTreeView::item:!selected:hover  {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    outline: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF
}

QListView::item:selected:hover, QListView::item:selected:hover, QTreeView::item:selected:hover  {
    background: #3d8ec9;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    height: 8px;
    background: #201F1F;
    margin: 2px 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
      stop: 0.0 silver, stop: 0.2 #a8a8a8, stop: 1 #727272);
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin: -4px 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

QSlider::groove:vertical {
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    width: 8px;
    background: #201F1F;
    margin: 0 0px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

QSlider::handle:vertical {
    background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0.0 silver,
    stop: 0.2 #a8a8a8, stop: 1 #727272);
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 0 -4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

QToolButton {
    /*  background-color: transparent; */
    border: 2px transparent #4A4949;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: dimgray;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}

QToolButton[popupMode="1"] { /* only for MenuButtonPopup */
 padding-right: 20px; /* make way for the popup button */
 border: 2px transparent #4A4949;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

QToolButton[popupMode="2"] { /* only for InstantPopup */
 padding-right: 10px; /* make way for the popup button */
 border: 2px transparent #4A4949;
}


QToolButton:hover, QToolButton::menu-button:hover {
    border: 2px solid #78879b;
}

QToolButton:checked, QToolButton:pressed,
    QToolButton::menu-button:pressed {
    background-color: #4A4949;
    border: 2px solid #78879b;
}

/* the subcontrol below is used only in the InstantPopup or DelayedPopup mode */
QToolButton::menu-indicator {
    image: url(images/down_arrow.png);
    top: -7px; left: -2px; /* shift it a bit */
}

/* the subcontrols below are used only in the MenuButtonPopup mode */
QToolButton::menu-button {
    border: 1px transparent #4A4949;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    /* 16px width + 4px for border = 20px allocated above */
    width: 16px;
    outline: none;
}

QToolButton::menu-arrow {
    image: url(images/down_arrow.png);
}

QToolButton::menu-arrow:open {
    top: 1px; left: 1px; /* shift it a bit */
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
}

QPushButton::menu-indicator  {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: bottom right;
    left: 4px;
}

QTableView
{
    border: 1px solid #444;
    gridline-color: #6c6c6c;
    background-color: #201F1F;
}


QTableView, QHeaderView
{
    border-radius: 0px;
}

QTableView::item:pressed, QListView::item:pressed, QTreeView::item:pressed  {
    background: #78879b;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

QTableView::item:selected:active, QTreeView::item:selected:active, QListView::item:selected:active  {
    background: #3d8ec9;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


QHeaderView
{
    border: 1px transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

QHeaderView::section  {
    background-color: #3A3939;
    color: silver;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

QHeaderView::section::vertical::first, QHeaderView::section::vertical::only-one
{
    border-top: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}

QHeaderView::section::vertical
{
    border-top: transparent;
}

QHeaderView::section::horizontal::first, QHeaderView::section::horizontal::only-one
{
    border-left: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}

QHeaderView::section::horizontal
{
    border-left: transparent;
}


QHeaderView::section:checked
 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #5A5959;
 }

 /* style the sort indicator */
QHeaderView::down-arrow {
    image: url(images/down_arrow.png);
}

QHeaderView::up-arrow {
    image: url(images/up_arrow.png);
}


QTableCornerButton::section {
    background-color: #3A3939;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

QToolBox  {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px transparent black;
}

QToolBox::tab {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    border: 1px solid #4A4949;
    border-bottom: 1px transparent #302F2F;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

 QToolBox::tab:selected { /* italicize selected tabs */
    font: italic;
    background-color: #302F2F;
    border-color: #3d8ec9;
 }

QStatusBar::item {
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    border-radius: 2px;
 }


QFrame[height="3"], QFrame[width="3"] {
    background-color: #AAA;
}


QSplitter::handle {
    border: 1px dashed #3A3939;
}

QSplitter::handle:hover {
    background-color: #787876;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
}

QSplitter::handle:horizontal {
    width: 1px;
}

QSplitter::handle:vertical {
    height: 1px;
}

QListWidget {
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

QListWidget::item {
    color: black;
}

QMessageBox {
    messagebox-critical-icon    : url(images/critical.png);
    messagebox-information-icon : url(images/information.png);
    messagebox-question-icon    : url(question.png);
    messagebox-warning-icon:    : url(images/warning.png);
}

ColorButton::enabled {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
}

ColorButton::disabled {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
```

Comment: That `image` folder is *not* an absolute path. Remove the first slash in the url: `image: url(images/down_arrow.png);`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, I even move the image inside the main folder and call it as image: `url(down_arrow.png);`, but again it is not shown ??

Comment: Are you running the script *from* its directory? Remember that relative paths are relative to the working directory. Please provide a basic [mre], including the image.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @zezo Why don't you use qresource?

Comment: I tried to look for examples to use qresource, but I couldn't use understandable one. How to use in a `.qss` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to use [QDir.addSearchPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setSearchPaths), which would allow you to use a simple alias in your stylesheet like this:

```css
QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(images:down_arrow_disabled.png);
}
```

The alias needs to be created at the beginning of the script, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    import os
    
    # use script directory as root
    root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))        
    QDir.addSearchPath('themes', os.path.join(root, 'themes'))
    QDir.addSearchPath('images', os.path.join(root, 'themes/images'))

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    file = QFile('themes:DarkBlue.qss')
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
    app.setStyleSheet(str(file.readAll(), 'utf-8'))
    ...
```

Note that this mechanism is also used to load the stylesheet itself (although it's not strictly necessary). It's best to avoid using normal relative paths, because they depend on the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) which can be changed independently. It's very unlikely to be the same every time your application is run, so you should never rely on it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the solution, but still, I have to add the relative path of the images and icons. For the stylesheet, it is not working as well. I tried `root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))       
print("The full path is", QDir.addSearchPath('themes', os.path.join(root, 'themes')))
` The output is None

Comment: I can't understand, why the `append` paths or your solution `addSearchPath` are not working ! and I have to use the relative path `for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(root):
        for f in filenames:
            yield os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))`

Comment: @zezo You seem to have completely misunderstood how this works. Qt will *automatically* substitute the key-name "images" with the search-path set using `QDir.addSearchPath`. So what you must do is replace all the uses of `images/xxx` in your stylesheet with `images:xxx`, and everything will work as expected (I know this, because I tested it). You can use these search-path key-names in any Qt API that takes a path. So in my answer, I also used `QFile('themes:DarkBlue.qss')`, which Qt will *automatically* expand to the full path (based on `root`).

Comment: @zezo I don't understand your second comment. Why are you using `os.walk`? There's no mention of that your question. What has that got to do with stylesheets? What you asked for is a way to use something like relative paths in your stylesheets. The `addSearchPaths` API does exactly that. (Note that in my answer, I assumed the `themes` folder is in the same folder as `main.py`. If it's not, you'll have to adjust the `root` accordingly).

Comment: Thank you. yes I have read the documentation of the `QDir`, and understand how the `addsearchpath` is working. I will be trying it in the style sheet. I was trying to use `os.walk` because I am importing modules (files) from different subdirectories, so I wanted directly import the name of the module without the subdirectoty and I thought it could work also for icons and images