# Extract course ids for instructors from json input

Tags: python, json

Let's say I've got a nested JSON file as below. If I want to print the courses that each instructor teaches, how do I do that?

```js
{
   "info":{
      "source_objects":[
         {
            "type":"sub-category",
            "id":277438897,
         }
      ],
      "item_type":"course",
      "items":[
         {
            "_class":"course",
            "id":156173119,
            "is_paid":null,
            "trainer":[
               {
                  "id":257585701,
                  "url":"/user/tania_guerra/",
               }
            ], 
      
         {
            "_class":"course",
            "id":12456,
            "is_paid":null,
            "trainer":[
               {
                  "id":257585701,
                  "url":"/user/tania_guerra/",
               }
            ], 
          } 
          *************and more data on the same format****************
       } 
   }
```

I'm not sure if there's any simple trick that I'm missing. So far, I've tried the following and it prints the course id and trainer id. But then how do I add all the courses that this trainer trains?

```python
with open (alljson, 'r') as json: # alljson is a directory where multiple json file exists 
  read_json = json.load(json) 
  
  for i in ange(int(len(read_all_json['info']['items']))): 
    cid = read_json['info']['items'][i]['id'] # gets the course id 
    for j in range(int(len(read_json['info']['items'][i]['trainer']))) 
      trainer_id = read_json['info']['items'][i]['trainer'][j]['id'] # gets the trainer id 
      
      # then how do I get course id added to trainer id. for example 
      # 12456---123456***123457***123454***12454 
      # trainer id--- all the courses that this instructor teaches addind ***
```

Comment: The structure of the example json is broken. How do the two "items" relate to each other? Why does one have a "trainer" key and the other "visible_instructors"? Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: @ ekhumoro sorry, I've copied part of the json as the actual files got huge information. I've edited the json info, hope this helps. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each trainer has a unique id, you can create a dict of lists, where the keys are trainer ids and the values are lists of course ids:

```
import os, json

rootdir = 'tmp/test1'

trainers = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:
        if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] != '.json':
            continue
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)

        with open(filepath) as stream:
            data = json.load(stream)

            for item in data['info']['items']:
                cid = item['id']
                for trainer in item['trainer']:
                    key = (trainer['id'], trainer['url'])
                    if key not in trainers:
                        trainers[key] = []
                    trainers[key].append(str(cid))

output = 'trainers.txt'

with open(output, 'w') as stream:
    for (tid, url), cids in sorted(trainers.items()):
        stream.write('%s---%s---%s\n' % (tid, url, ';;;'.join(cids)))
```

Result:

```
257585701---/user/tania_guerra/---12456;;;7992450;;;7812756;;;156173119;;;562456
918585703---/user/tania_guerra/---7867833;;;14473169;;;156173119
```

*test.json*:

```
{
  "info": {
    "source_objects": [
      {
        "type": "sub-category",
        "id": 277438897
      }
    ],
    "item_type": "course",
    "items": [
      {
        "_class": "course",
        "id": 156173119,
        "is_paid": null,
        "trainer": [
          {
            "id": 257585701,
            "url": "/user/tania_guerra/"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_class": "course",
        "id": 12456,
        "is_paid": null,
        "trainer": [
          {
            "id": 257585701,
            "url": "/user/tania_guerra/"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: When I'm trying your code, it seems that the tid is repeating and getting cid from that section. like {257585701: [156173119] , 257585701:[12456]}. I'm not sure if I'm missing something?

Comment: @Tech My code produces `{257585701: [156173119, 12456]}`. The keys of a dict cannot be duplicated, so what you show isn't possible. Are you talking about *your* code, or mine? My code works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ ekhumoro I'm not sure if this has something to do with multiple json file in multiple directories. I'm guessing from your code its getting the duplicate from each jsoon file and returning them as dict. and therefore I'm having like 100s of dicts. Any idea how can we merge all in one

Comment: @Tech You didn't mention multiple files in your question. I can adapt my answer to handle that. Are all the json files in the same directory, and do they all have the same structure?

Comment: @ ekhumoro they have subdirectories and yes they have the same structure

Comment: @Tech So you want to recurse through all sub-directories as well? I will update my answer shortly. (PS: I would appreciate if you upvoted my answer in the meantime, as it is already essentially correct).

Comment: @ ekhumoro yes, I would like the code to check all the json files in all subdirectories and return the result. I've upvoted your answer

Comment: @Tech Thanks. I have now updated my answer. I only tested using a small group of files/dirs based on your json example, but it should work okay for you. All the trainers from all files will be in one dict. (Note that I assumed all your json files have a ".json" extension).

Comment: @ ekhumoro you're brilliant. Thank you so much. I'll have more questions about python which I'll later submit in separate questions. Your skill would be highly appreciated. I wish I can upvote you millions lol

Comment: @ ekhumoro your code prints the result exactly how I want it. something like {12345: [courseid1, courseid2.......]}Now, if I want to print out in a format like tid---url--courseid1;;;courseid2 etc. How do I do that? Should I post another question and share you the link?

Comment: @Tech You could use a tuple for the key. So instead of `tid = trainer['id']`, do `tid = (trainer['id'], trainer['url'])`. (You might want to change the variable name from `tid` to `key`). Note that this will only work correctly if the trainer's url is always spelled exactly the same. If that's not the case, it might be necessary to normalise the urls.

Comment: I tried creating tuple and it works but how can I join them using --- and course id to ;;;? I was looking for something like tid---url--courseid1;;;courseid2 in each line of the print result. Tuple gives me like {(tid,url: [courseid1, courseid2])}

Comment: @Tech Are you sure you want to do that? It would mean you can no longer look up trainers by id. It's possible that a better structure would to keep the tid as key, and have the values as a tuple of (url, cids) instead. Or perhaps even use a simple dict for the values. It really all depends on how you intend to use the data. You need to think carefully about that first, and then pick a structure that is best suited to how it will be used.

Comment: @Tech Do you actually need to use the `trainers` dict in another part of your program? Or do you just want to save the result in a text file, or something?

Comment: @ ekhumoro thats how I've been asked to get the data. So in each line of the print result, it'd be something like tid---url---courseid1;;;courseid2

Comment: @ ekhumoro, yes you're correct, I need to save the info in a txt file

Comment: @Tech Using *literally* that structure? So with three hyphens after the first two items and then three semi-colons separating the rest?

Comment: @ ekhumoro Yes three hyphens after the first two items and then three semi-colons separating the rest. This needs to be written in the txt file as one line for each tid, meaning print the result tid---url---courseid1;;;courseid2 format. Each tid will have one line.

Comment: @Tech Okay, I have updated my answer with what I hope is an acceptable solution. (PS: as a return favour, would you mind upvoting a couple of my other answers - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70635607/984421) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71929259/984421)).

Comment: @ ekhumoro I've upvoted your answers. For your code, it seems like now I'm getting only one courseid printed to each trainer rather than all the courses that this trainer trains

Comment: @Tech As I suggested earlier, that might be because the urls aren't identical. The code in my answer works fine with my simple test data, but your real data is probably different. Can you check some of the urls? Are they totally consistent? Are some missing?

Comment: @ ekhumoro I think its because the tid, url combination as key is not same for all instructor and therefor when we say if key not in trainers, it gets only the first courseid for the trainer and avoids rest.

Comment: @Tech Okay, but that means you will need a list of urls for each trainer, right? Or you need to come up with some way to choose which one is correct. Obviously, I can't make any suggestions regarding that, because I can't see your real data. How exactly do the urls differ?

Comment: @ ekhumoro is there a way I can send you a photo of my code. I appreciate your help

Comment: @Tech I've changed my answer so that it sorts by tid. That should make it easier for you to see how the urls differ for each trainer. Are some urls empty? Do they just have extra slashes? Or are they completely different? What exactly is the format of the real urls? If the url is different for each course, maybe the structure should be something like `tid---cid=url;;;cid=url;;;cid=url`.

Comment: @Tech Did you solve the above issue with the urls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245389/discussion-between-tech-and-ekhumoro).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest to use a `dict` or better a `defaultdict[int->List[int]]`

something like

```py
from collections import defaultdict

with open(alljson, "r") as json:
    items = json["info"]["items"]
trainer_course_mapping = defaultdict(list)

for item in items:
    trainers = item["trainer"]
    for trainer in trainers:
        trainer_course_mapping[trainer["id"]].append(item["id"])
```